# How to merge two tables fullfilling a field with his minimum value?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to complete my data but i can't find a good solution for this.

I am working with periods generated dynamically (sample projection).
I don't know if this is the better idea to recreate a table only to join on my table TREND.

```
-- SQL CODE TO RECREATE MY TREND TABLE
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.TREND(
Asset STRING,
Metric_Code STRING,
Metric_V FLOAT64,
Trend FLOAT64,
YearMonth INT64,
YearMonthRank INT64
);
INSERT INTO test.TREND
VALUES ('RDX4', 'AXCP32', 88.0853212, 89.0853212, 202103,1),
('RDX4', 'AXCP32', 88.0853212,85.0853212, 202106,2),
('RDX4', 'AXCP34', 79.41087028,81.0853212, 202103,3),
('RDX4', 'AXCP34', 70.44587,69.0853212, 202106,4),
('MRDX4', 'AXCP32', 88.0853212, 89.0853212, 202103,1),
('MRDX4', 'AXCP32', 88.0853212,85.0853212, 202106,2),
('MRDX4', 'AXCP34', 79.41087028,81.0853212, 202103,3),
('MRDX4', 'AXCP34', 70.44587, 69.0853212,202106,4);

-- SQL CODE TO RECREATE MY PROJECTION TABLE
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.PROJECTION(
Asset STRING,
Metric_Code STRING,
Metric_V FLOAT64,
Trend FLOAT64,
YearMonth INT64,
YearMonthRank INT64
);
INSERT INTO PROJECTION
VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202103,1),
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202106,2),
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202109,3),
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202112,4),
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202203,5),
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202206,6),
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202209,7),
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202212,8);
```

Now i am stuck, i can't merge data correctly to calculate my prediction on it.
I tried to coalesce on Asset ,Metric_Code and trend but it doesn't work like you can imagine:

```
SELECT COALESCE(B.Asset,(SELECT C.asset FROM gopass.TREND C WHERE C.YearMonthRank=1 AND B.asset=C.asset)) AS Asset,
B.Metric_Code,
B.Metric_V,
B.Trend,
A.YearMonth,
A.YearMonthRank
FROM gopass.PROJECTION A
LEFT JOIN gopass.TREND B  ON A.YearMonthRank = B.YearMonthRank
ORDER BY Asset ASC;
```

I have no idea how to generate an output as below.
For each Asset + Metric_Code couple , i need to fill the YearMonth & YearMonthRank columns too.

After that i will be able to add my prediction column !

| Asset | Metric_Code | Metric_V | Trend | YearMonth | YearMonthRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RDX4 | AXCP32 | 88.0853212 | 89.0853212 | 202103 | 1 |
| RDX4 | AXCP32 | 88.0853212 | 85.0853212 | 202106 | 2 |
| RDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202109 | 3 |
| RDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202112 | 4 |
| RDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202203 | 5 |
| RDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202206 | 6 |
| RDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202209 | 7 |
| RDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202212 | 8 |
| RDX4 | AXCP34 | 79.41087028 | 81.0853212 | 202103 | 1 |
| RDX4 | AXCP34 | 70.44587 | 69.0853212 | 202106 | 2 |
| RDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202109 | 3 |
| RDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202112 | 4 |
| RDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202203 | 5 |
| RDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202206 | 6 |
| RDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202209 | 7 |
| RDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202212 | 8 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP32 | 88.0853212 | 89.0853212 | 202103 | 1 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP32 | 88.0853212 | 85.0853212 | 202106 | 2 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202109 | 3 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202112 | 4 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202203 | 5 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202206 | 6 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202209 | 7 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP32 |  |  | 202212 | 8 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP34 | 79.41087028 | 81.0853212 | 202103 | 1 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP34 | 70.44587 | 81.0853212 | 202106 | 2 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202109 | 3 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202112 | 4 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202203 | 5 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202206 | 6 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202209 | 7 |
| MRDX4 | AXCP34 |  |  | 202212 | 8 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

> For each Asset + Metric_Code couple , i need to fill the YearMonth & YearMonthRank columns too

For this, Below query is expanding `PROJECTION` table for each (`Asset`, `Metric_Code`) combination by `CROSS JOIN` first.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE TREND (
  Asset STRING,
  Metric_Code STRING,
  Metric_V FLOAT64,
  Trend FLOAT64,
  YearMonth INT64,
  YearMonthRank INT64
);
INSERT INTO TREND
VALUES ('RDX4', 'AXCP32', 88.0853212, 89.0853212, 202103,1),
       ('RDX4', 'AXCP32', 88.0853212,85.0853212, 202106,2),
       ('RDX4', 'AXCP34', 79.41087028,81.0853212, 202103,3),
       ('RDX4', 'AXCP34', 70.44587,69.0853212, 202106,4),
       ('MRDX4', 'AXCP32', 88.0853212, 89.0853212, 202103,1),
       ('MRDX4', 'AXCP32', 88.0853212,85.0853212, 202106,2),
       ('MRDX4', 'AXCP34', 79.41087028,81.0853212, 202103,3),
       ('MRDX4', 'AXCP34', 70.44587, 69.0853212,202106,4)
;

-- SQL CODE TO RECREATE MY PROJECTION TABLE
CREATE TEMP TABLE PROJECTION (
  Asset STRING,
  Metric_Code STRING,
  Metric_V FLOAT64,
  Trend FLOAT64,
  YearMonth INT64,
  YearMonthRank INT64
);
INSERT INTO PROJECTION
VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202103,1),
       (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202106,2),
       (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202109,3),
       (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202112,4),
       (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202203,5),
       (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202206,6),
       (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202209,7),
       (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 202212,8)
;

SELECT B.Asset_Key AS Asset,
       B.Metric_Code_Key AS Metric_Code,
       C.Metric_V,
       C.Trend,
       A.YearMonth,
       A.YearMonthRank
  FROM PROJECTION A
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Asset AS Asset_Key, Metric_Code AS Metric_Code_Key FROM TREND) B
  LEFT JOIN TREND C
    ON B.Asset_Key = C.Asset AND B.Metric_Code_Key = C.Metric_Code AND A.YearMonthRank = C.YearMonthRank
 ORDER BY 1, 2, A.YearMonthRank;
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaytiger ! I see how to use cross join well now !